# Nesting of Sql Statements

Tags: ios, sqlite

Hi i have made a function in my app delegate to remove the redundancy of my database , I am not sure do i have coded right as i have to perform nesting of SQL statements to find out the error in DB.

Can any body suggest me where i am wrong because the application is running well in simulator and crashing in Device.

I am even Not Sure where to Put finalize and sqlite3_close . Kindly help

```
 -(void) removeRedundancy2
    {
        NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        dbPathString = [[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"turfnutritiontool_ver_99.db"];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;
        sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt1;
        BOOL isMyFileThere = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString];

        if (isMyFileThere)
        {
            if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &database1)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                // TO REMOVE FROM from tnt_scenario_product when NO ProductID Found

                NSString *querySql2= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT productid from tnt_scenarioproduct"];
                const char* query_sql2 = [querySql2 UTF8String];

                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, query_sql2, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    int productid =  sqlite3_column_int(selectStmt, 0);
                    // NSLog(@"ProductId1 =%d",productid);

                    NSString *querySql21= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT productid from tnt_productcontent WHERE productid = %d",productid];
                    const char* query_sql21 = [querySql21 UTF8String];

                    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, query_sql21, -1, &selectStmt1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        if (sqlite3_step(selectStmt1) == SQLITE_ROW)
                        {
                            // DO NOTHING
                        }
                        else
                        {   // to delete scenario without product id
                            NSLog(@"Delete this Product from TPC 2 %d",productid);
                            NSString *querydelete2= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE from tnt_scenarioproduct WHERE productid = %d",productid];

                            const char* query_delete2 = [querydelete2 UTF8String];
                            char *error;
                            sqlite3_exec(database1, query_delete2, NULL, NULL, &error);
                            NSLog(@"error=%s ",error);
                            sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt1);
                        }
                    }
                    sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt1);
                    sqlite3_close(database1);

                }
                sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
            }
            sqlite3_close(database1);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [sqlite3_open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)/[close](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html)/[prepare](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)/[finalize](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html)?

Comment: i have used nested statements so i am not able to catch where to put finalize and close :(

Comment: So you don't understand how (Objective) C works?

Comment: yup i am not able to understand how to perfectly release the sql statements and Database variable also . :( , it Will be great if you make my code perfect :|

Answer (score 0):

After calling `sqlite3_open`, you *must* call `sqlite3_close` for that connection exactly once.
After calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, you *must* call `sqlite3_finalize` for that statement exactly once.

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &database1)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, query_sql21, -1, &selectStmt1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        ...
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectStmt);
    ....
}
sqlite3_close(database1);
```

Furthermore, you should not reuse the same variable (`selectStmt`) for two different queries to prevent confusion about its lifetime.